# Magento which model is correct for getting the quote in the cart?

Tags: quote, coupon, enterprise-1.14

I have tried every different combo of model that returns a quote in order to try and find the one that has the quote for the current customer's cart.

So far none of them work, and I can't figure out why this might be.

Essentially I'm running an external script in the misc directory that sets a generated coupon code on the current cart, but none of the following set the code correctly and I have to default to redirecting to /checkout/cart/coupon/post or whatever the correct url is for that.

Here are the different models I have tried for getting the session:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
```

And these are the different method's I've tried to run on the quote:

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->setCartCouponCode($coupon);
$quote->setCouponCode($coupon);
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
```

They don't fail but they also do not set the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    echo $mageFilename . " was not found";
    exit;
}
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();

// This has to run to authenticate customer and checkout session calls.
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

$couponCode = "COUPON_TEST"; // Make sure to use the valid coupon here

$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
$quote->collectTotals();

$quote->save();

die("Applied coupon $couponCode successfully!");
```

Comment: Rather than echo $couponcode, it might be better to echo $quote->getCouponCode() since that's usually where I figure out it didn't set correctly but thanks I will try this now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not apply a coupon code for me it still has no coupon code when getting to checkout :(

Comment: Did you use the correct coupon code instead of "COUPON_TEST"?

Comment: Yes, I cut and pasted all parts of your code but replaced $couponCode with my own variable that I know contains a working code because it can be passed through the url to be applied.

Comment: I tested it and it worked fine on my end. Did you try to create a file in the webroot folder and then testing it?

Comment: What do you mean by the webroot folder, I have it in the misc directory currently.

Comment: I mean like this https://screencast.com/t/C9TmMNenot8

Where is your misc directory? Did you access to that file via the browser?

Comment: Apologies, I've had that directory for so long I forgot it wasn't a built-in one, yes it is at the webroot, it is essentially website . com / misc / applycoupon.php.

Comment: Did you access to that file via the web browser?

Comment: Yes, I accessed it via chrome with the url similar to how I commented it above

Comment: Is this on your localhost instance? Do you have a remote instance so I can test?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's on a local instance and I don't think I am able to port forward

Comment: This is the video showing how I tested it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cetpF_3P3VLEaCz38OUna71AgbVPfjD4/view

Btw, you can test it on this site https://jm.bolt.devzn.com/

Comment: I'm not sure what could be the cause, I will have to look more into which session/quote it is using to try and apply that too because it has to be possible on my instance to apply a coupon code as it does work in some cases. I guess its just a matter of figuring out what the difference is between the Magento core code and mine that doesn't let mine work.

Comment: Yes, good luck with that. I think there is some custom module that causes the issue.